# Visual Studio says Norton is slowing build performance despite whitelisting directories

Tags: android-studio, norton

In Visual Studio 3.5.3, I get the following error:

> "Your anti-virus program might be impacting your build performance. Android Studio checked the following directories:..."

Despite adding the directories to Norton 22.19.9.63's "Items to Exclude from Auto-Protect, Script Control, SONAR and Download Intelligence Detection", Visual Studio still occasionally shows the same error.

Does anyone know how fix this problem?